# Meteor Email package sends the email to the same email address

Tags: email, meteor

I am working on an application that sends email after a verification process. The email works, however it sends only to the same email address, even though the data has different email addresses for the `from` and `to` options. I already tried hard-coding the email addresses:

```
Email.send({
  from: "xxxx1@gmail.com",
  to: "xxxx2@gmail.com",
  subject: 'Feedback',
  text: data.enquiry
})
```

But it sends to `xxxx1@gmail.com`.  How do I fix this one?

Comment: It's correct, because it sends to the 'to:' field, which is 'xxxx2@gmail.com'.

Comment: Also, if you plan to send email from a gmail address, (unless you're using the correct SMTP credentials to send through gmail) you're not going to have a good time. A lot of your emails will end up in spam or silently discarded.

Comment: Seems to be rather an issue with your email server then